# Android application stops

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, android-arrayadapter

When app loads this activity it stops working.Below is my code for main activity, logcat and required array. Please help me resolve this issue. In this, when user selects any item from spinner then according to selected item another list item loads results.

MainActivity:

```
Button cropPrice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(){

        final Context context = this;

        cropPrice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        cropPrice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0){

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CropPrice.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

CropPrice.java

```
public static String itemsa = "guj";

// List view
private ListView lv;
// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.crop_price);

    Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    String[] courses={"guj","con","raj"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,courses);
    state.setAdapter(adapter1); 
    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
                int position, long itemId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            itemsa = av.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", getPackageName());
         final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});

    // Listview Data
  //  Intent intent = new Intent();
    // ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.inputSearch))).setText(intent.getStringExtra("selected"));
    //int id = Context.getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", 
          //  context.getPackageName());

    //String products[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(id);
    //final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guj);
    //int resourceId = R.array.class.getField(Integer.parseInt(itemsa));
    //final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
    //int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "Array",
        //       this.getPackageName());

     //  String[] products = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);
    //String itemName = itemsa;
    //String getRes = "R.array."+ itemName;
    //final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray("getRes");
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            if(count == 0)
            {
                tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            submitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CropPrice.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            if(cs.length()== 0){
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    inputSearch.setText((String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                    cont = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="raj">
    <item >raja</item>
    <item >rajb</item>        
</string-array>
<string-array name="Countreis">
    <item >manish</item>
    <item >India</item>          
</string-array>
<string-array name="guj">
    <item >guja</item>
    <item >gujb</item>         
</string-array>
```

Logcat:

```
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Process: com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse, PID: 2883
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse/com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse.CropPrice}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:141)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse.CropPrice.onCreate(CropPrice.java:128)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
01-03 06:11:20.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: The problem is in line 144 (at com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse.CropPrice.onCreate(CropPrice.java:114)) BUT you only gave us 95 lines of code...hmmmm

Comment: else block is at line 144: }else{ lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt initialize the `itemsa` variable initially.
change the line for like this:
initialize by default some value.

```
public static String itemsa="guj";
```

change these lines also:

```
String[] courses={"guj","con","raj"};
```

to

```
String[] courses={"raj","Countreis","guj"};
```

**EDIT:**

```
public static String itemsa = "guj";

    // List view
    private ListView lv;
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crop_price);

        Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        String[] courses={"guj","Countreis","raj"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,courses);
        state.setAdapter(adapter1); 
        state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
                    int position, long itemId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                itemsa = av.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", getPackageName());
             final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
             updateList(products);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});

        int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", getPackageName());
        final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);

        updateList(products);
    }

    private void updateList(String[] products) {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                if(count == 0)
                {
                    tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                submitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                CropPrice.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                if(cs.length()== 0){
                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        inputSearch.setText((String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                        cont = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });     
    }
```

Comment: when I initializes variable then it only loads guj array, either I select guj or anything else from spinner it only loads "guj" array, please help me, what should I need to do?

Comment: and call this method also, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in  OnItemSelectedListener() method.

Comment: I had put this lines int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", getPackageName());
final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2); inside spinner item selected listener and declared products string globally, then again it tells same error, nullpointerexception.

Comment: place your current stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse/com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse.CropPrice}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
01-03 05:38:08.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-03 05:38:08.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-03 05:38:08.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)

Comment: where you start the activity com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse/com.finaldbparse.finaldbparse.CropPr‌​ice

Comment: I had put one button on mainactivity activity, when I click this button  cropprice.java activity starts.

Comment: please post the code, then only we can give the solution?

Comment: what is storage=null, in your exception, where you menction it.

Comment: No where, I hadn't mentioned storage anywhere in code, but you can check complete logcat above, I had edited it to new logcat.

Comment: again same error, nothing is going to be work fine, please give me any suggestion to resolve this issue, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: place try catch block for every method, and print the error where you faced the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68117/discussion-between-ravi-bhalodiya-and-balaji-koduri).

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null

Because `getResources().getIdentifier` executing when `onCreate` method called but you are setting value in `itemsa` on `onItemSelected` of Spinner.

So you will need to put null check before calling `getResources().getIdentifier` or initialize `itemsa` with some default value:

Answer (score 0):

use `try-catch` block to monitor errors like this,

```
try{
Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

String[] courses={"guj","con","raj"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,courses);
state.setAdapter(adapter1); 
state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
            int position, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        itemsa = av.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});

  // Listview Data
  //  Intent intent = new Intent();
// ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.inputSearch))).setText(intent.getStringExtra("selected"));
//int id = Context.getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", 
      //  context.getPackageName());

//String products[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(id);
//final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guj);
int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "array", getPackageName());
final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
//int resourceId = R.array.class.getField(Integer.parseInt(itemsa));
//final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
//int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier(itemsa, "Array",
    //       this.getPackageName());

 //  String[] products = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);
//String itemName = itemsa;
//String getRes = "R.array."+ itemName;
//final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray("getRes");
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        if(count == 0)
        {
            tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        CropPrice.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        if(cs.length()== 0){
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                inputSearch.setText((String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                cont = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
}catch(Exception e){

//display e in toast
Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, duration).show();
}
```